If $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian, is $e^{\hat{Q}}$ Hermitian?
I claim that if $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian, $e^{\hat{Q}}$ is Hermitian. I reason as follows:

If $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian, $c\hat{Q}$ is also Hermitian, where c is a real constant.
If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are Hermitian, so is $\hat{A} + \hat{B}$
If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute and are Hermitian, $\hat{A}  \hat{B}$ is Hermitian. Since $\hat{Q}$ commutes with itself, so $\hat{Q^n}$ is Hermitian.
Thus, any real polynomial of $\hat{Q}$ is also Hermitian.
Since $e^{\hat{Q}}$ is a real polynomial series of $\hat{Q}$ , and all its terms are Hermitian, thus, $e^{\hat{Q}}$ is Hermitian.

I have no confusion in the first 4 steps. But I am not sure if the last step works, since $e^x$ is an infinite series. Can we say the same about any real function with a Taylor Series expansion?

Note that questions of the form "Is this correct?" are generally bad fits for this Q&A site because the answer (i.e., Yes or No) is too short to be considered a valid answer. You should consider adjusting your question to be a little more open opened.

Your proof seems correct. Why do you doubt it?

I was stuck trying to check if $e^{i \frac{d}{dx}}$ is Hermitian. Google and ChatGPT was arguing it to not be Hermitian.

Well, ChatGPT and Google’s AIs can’t do physics and can’t really do math either.

This question is similar to: When a function of the position operator is self-adjoint?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Another interesting problem is to show that for a hermitian $\hat{Q}$, $e^{i\hat{Q}}$ is unitary and not hermitian. This then relates to the time evolution operator.
